# I have one million record in mongodb could not able to fetch record

Tags: java, mongodb

Trying to fetch data from mongodb using java but my code will take more time to fetch the record.

the mongodb data is very big 1 million record there in mongo db.

```
           MongoDatabase database = config.getCollection();
           String docName = slpitDName[i];
           MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(docName);
           BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
           whereQuery.put("flag", 0);
           List<Document> documents = (List<Document>) collection.find(whereQuery).into(new 
           ArrayList<Document>());
```

Comment: Have you created any indexes on your collection?

Comment: yes i created index on  column name flag

Comment: Please run the same query in Mongo Shell with `explain('executionStats')` and post the query plan output.